# Load Balancing with Apache Traffic Server

Tags: load-balancing, apache-traffic-server

I was looking to use Apache Traffic Server for its reverse proxy functionality, but I also need it to load balance across clusters of servers. The documentation mentions load balancing, but I cannot find any details about it. Could someone please confirm one way or the other, and if it does support it, could you please provide a pointer to the documentation.

Comment: I have concluded that ATS does not support load balancing. I have used NGINX instead. This worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need mod_proxy & mod_proxy_balancer, per [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)

Comment: Can you use Apache Server Mod files with Traffic Server?

Comment: ah, after a look at [Apache Traffic Server](http://trafficserver.apache.org/) I see the docs are sparse as you suggested, but imagine this software is intended to run in front of a set of Apache servers.  Not sure what you mean exactly by 'Apache Server Mod'.

Comment: I suppose that you could put Traffic Server in front of a Apache servers with mod_proxy_balancer running on them, but that seems like an unnecessary complication unless you are also using Traffic Server's caching ability. What I was hoping for is that Traffic Server supported load balancing directly, but I don't think that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Apache Traffic Server only supports round robin load balancing using dns to resolve to multiple origins.

There is a plugin which offers more advanced balancing capabilities though:

https://github.com/apache/trafficserver/tree/master/plugins/experimental/balancer